# Dealing with a dataset having target values on different scales?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, scales

I am currently working on a dataset having **10 features** and **one continuous target variable**. One of the features is **'Country'** , in which there are **seven unique values [Argentina ,Denmark , France...etc].**

Now , the continuous target variable is **sales of a given product in that particular country for a given month in a given year**.

It has been given in the problem statement , **that the Sales have been taken in the local currency of that country** , so now I have values on different scales and I am not sure how to deal with them.

When I grouped the data as per the different countries , (using pandas's groupby function) , I got at least **1000 observations for each country**. So maybe I could **train a model separately for each country** ? All kind of approaches will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to model. To model local effects, you can leave the target as is and train separate models for each country. If you are interested in how some factors may be correlating with increased/decreased sales in all countries, you could one-hot encode the 'Country' feature and fit the model to your full dataset. The 'Country' contribution should then be essentially the intercept needed to adjust the target for that country.

You may want to consider taking a logarithm of the sales, as you probably care more about the percentage change in the target rather than absolute change. Also, depending on what drives Sales, you may want to consider converting them to a common currency, e.g. USD - depending on whether they are more stable in local currency or in USD.

Comment: I converted them to a common currency and am now getting improved results. But there is a problem , around 1000 of the sales values are negative and 5000 of them are zero. How do I deal with this?

Comment: It really depends on why they are negative/zero and what you are trying to model.

Comment: I am trying to predict the sales, so negative could possibly mean the seller incurred losses. While zero could mean , the products were not sold or no net loss. I am thinking of making a separate classifier to first predict whether the product got positive sales or negative sales.Then run a regressor to predict the sales. But the problem is that the negative sales predictions are far less in number to the positive sales ones.

Comment: country intercept won't help, since the intercept adds a constant, while different currencies are multiples of each-other

Comment: Converting to a common currency was my first thought, but the conversion between, say, dollars are euros is not constant like the conversion between centimeters and meters. Converting to a common currency might be the way to go, but I want to mention that it might not be as straightforward as a unit conversion sounds.